# Flink application execution in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-flink

How to run flink application in windows eclipse IDE?can we configure Flink runtime env as we register a tomcat server in eclipse

Comment: https://training.ververica.com/devEnvSetup.html might help you get started.

Answer (score 2):

Apache flink can be added as a dependency to the project, and can be imported in any IDE .

Here is an example for maven :

```
<dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.0</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.12</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.0</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
```

If you also would like to see the running job's dag on web ui, you can add this depdendency, and goto http://localhost:8081.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-runtime-web_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```